# How to generate UUID in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

Is there a way to `generate UUID` of the following format in the robot framework? Can we use a similar python library e.g. `UUID library`?

Format-

> 07464f5d-db6e-486e-bdfa-ad50b2ad8a92
>
> fd61836f-5745-47c2-a9b1-b13335e11695

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Evaluate`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword to call [what](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) was suggested in the comments.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Generate UUID
    ${uuid}=    Evaluate    uuid.uuid4()    modules=uuid
```

[image]

Or you could use [Inline Python evaluation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id117) since Robot Framework 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [robotframework-faker](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-faker/) library
after installing through pip, You can use it like, e.g.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    FakerLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Print uuid
    ${some_uuid}    Uuid 4
    Log    ${some_uuid}
```